# Is it possible to submit a form without refreshing the page to the action page?

Tags: php

Is there a way to submit a form like this without refreshing the page and going to the first page, for example if we have two pages, this code will make the page refresh to the first page. I have suggested to use ajax, but I was turned down.

```
<form action="/page.php?pageAction=POSTS&amp;pageID=1&amp;subPageID=2" method="post" name="page" id="addPageLink" enctype="multipart/form-data">

... The Form Code goes here

<input type="submit" class="mt_btn" name="frmAddLink" id="addPageLink" value="Post">
</form>
```

I have thought about adding the page to the action like this, so that if the page refreshes, at least it refreshes on the same page.

```
<form action="/page.php?pageAction=POSTS&amp;pageID=1&amp;subPageID=2&amp;pagen=2" method="post" name="page" id="addPageLink" enctype="multipart/form-data">

... The Form Code goes here

<input type="submit" class="mt_btn" name="frmAddLink" id="addPageLink" value="Post">
</form>
```

Is this even possible? will messing with the action by adding hashes affect anything?

Comment: Umm, yes. This has been done since forever of foreverness. `if(isset($_POST['pageAction'])){ /* the form was submitted, show success message? */ }else{ /* this is a fresh form, so show the form? */}`.

Comment: Have a look here for a monkeypatch approach: **hidden iframe submission**. This is more relevant when you're submitting to a URL on another server/app. https://morningstudio.com.au/blog/2013/06/how-to-style-google-forms/

Comment: jquery/ajax is for sure the best option, but since that is not allowed, I recommend MoneyZeus's approach.

Comment: target="_blank" also works on <form> Maybe this is enough?